# rendertype inputlink for huge files without copying the file

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

I need a tca field with a link to huge files (100-900 MB). I used this TCA:

```
'config' => [
    'type' => 'input',
    'renderType' => 'inputLink',
    'fieldControl' => [
        'linkPopup' => [
            'options' => [
                'blindLinkOptions' => 'mail,page,spec,url,folder',
                'blindLinkFields' => 'class,params,target,title',
            ],
        ],
    ],
]
```

It works but when I save the data TYPO3 seems to copy the file and I get the error message that the limit of 50 MB is exceeded. But I need only a simple link to the file.

In version 7 it worked with this code:

```
'config' => array (
    'type' => 'input',
    'size' => '100',
    'max' => '255',
    'eval' => 'trim',
    'wizards' => array(
        '_PADDING' => 2,
        'link' => array(
            'type' => 'popup',
            'title' => 'LLL:EXT:cms/locallang_ttc.xml:header_link_formlabel',
            'icon' => 'link_popup.gif',
            'module' => array(
                'name' => 'wizard_element_browser',
                'urlParameters' => array(
                    'mode' => 'wizard',
                    'act' => 'file'
                )
            ),
            'JSopenParams' => 'height=300,width=500,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1'
        )
    ),
)
```

but it doesn't work anymore in TYPO3 8.

How can i fix the problem?

---

Correction:

I am sorry but I was wrong. The whole question is wrong: The above configuration works as expected, it does *not* copy the file, it only links to the file. I made another error which leads to a misunderstanding of my real problem.

Sorry for the noise ...
In order to close the topic I will mark the answer as correct. In some way it was because it gave me a good hint.

Comment: Is it possible selection of classes from multiple classes for CSS-Class for renderType "InputLink" field sane as we add class for RTE link? https://prnt.sc/vd2gtu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to [FAL](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-fal/8.7/en-us/UsingFal/Tca/Index.html). Here the files are only referenced to the orgin file.

```
'image' => array(
        'label' => 'LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_general.xlf:LGL.images',
        'config' => \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::getFileFieldTCAConfig('image', array(
                'appearance' => array(
                        'createNewRelationLinkTitle' => 'LLL:EXT:frontend/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_ttc.xlf:images.addFileReference'
                ),
                // custom configuration for displaying fields in the overlay/reference table
                // to use the imageoverlayPalette instead of the basicoverlayPalette
                'foreign_types' => array(
                        ...
                )
        ), $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['GFX']['imagefile_ext'])
),
```